# secureTextEntry is changing font family React Native

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building a form for login that contains username and password fields with React Native using the **TextInput** component and for the password field, I'm passing the **secureTextEntry** prop as follows:

```
<TextInput
value={password}    
onChangeText={(e)=>setPassword(e)}
style={styles.password}
secureTextEntry={true}
```

But I faced an issue where fontFamily style is not applying on the TextInput with **secureTextEntry** prop. I figured out a solution that worked ONLY on IOS but NOT on Android by writing the following:

added `ref={ref => ref_1 = ref}` prop for password textInput so it becomes as follows:

```
  <TextInput
    value={password}    
    onChangeText={(e)=>setPassword(e)}
    style={styles.password}
    secureTextEntry={true} 
    ref={ref => ref_1 = ref}
```

trying to set the style on useEffect

```
let ref_1 =  useRef(null)
  useEffect(()=>{

    ref_1.setNativeProps({
        style:{
          fontFamily:fonts.dinRegular
        }
    })
  
  },[])
```

But now I have a bug where the whole placeholder is disappearing on ANDROID completely but working perfectly on IOS...

Any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/30164)

The problem was solved by just updating Expo!

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

```
const inputRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    if(inputRef && inputRef.current){
      inputRef.current.setNativeProps({ style: {fontFamily: 'YOUR-FONT-FAMILY'} })
    }    
}, [inputRef.current]);



<TextInput ref={inputRef} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
ref_1.current.setNativeProps({
        style:{
          fontFamily:fonts.dinRegular
        }
})
```

Comment: When I write ref_1.current.setNativeProps instead of ref_1.setNativeProps it will return Undefined. In other words, the function is working perfectly but NOT on ANDROID